How to check two Excel files for equality?
I'm using Apache POI to create Excel files.
I want to write a test that creates an Excel file and checks whether its contents are the same as the contents of the other Excel file.
First I thought about comparing the checksums of the files but they turned out to be different although I compared the checksums of the files created by the same test. And they definitely must have the same contents.
Then I extracted the contents of a xlsx-file (seems to be a ZIP-file) and compared the corresponding folder contents. There was a file that contained Excel creation date. This of course changes from one test run to the other. Below are my actions described above executed in a terminal:
Excel file file1.xlsx and file2.xlsx are created by the same procedure and their contents don't differ.
$ unzip file1.xlsx -d /tmp/file1
Archive:  file1.xlsx
  inflating: file1/[Content_Types].xml  
  inflating: file1/_rels/.rels       
  inflating: file1/docProps/app.xml  
  inflating: file1/docProps/core.xml  
  inflating: file1/xl/sharedStrings.xml  
  inflating: file1/xl/styles.xml     
  inflating: file1/xl/workbook.xml   
  inflating: file1/xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels  
  inflating: file1/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml  

$ unzip file2.xlsx -d /tmp/file2
Archive:  file2.xlsx
  inflating: file2/[Content_Types].xml  
  inflating: file2/_rels/.rels       
  inflating: file2/docProps/app.xml  
  inflating: file2/docProps/core.xml  
  inflating: file2/xl/sharedStrings.xml  
  inflating: file2/xl/styles.xml     
  inflating: file2/xl/workbook.xml   
  inflating: file2/xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels  
  inflating: file2/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml  

# File containing Excel creation date
$ diff --brief --recursive /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
Files /tmp/file1/docProps/core.xml and /tmp/file2/docProps/core.xml differ

$ diff <(xmllint --format /tmp/file1/docProps/core.xml) <(xmllint --format /tmp/file2/docProps/core.xml)
3c3
<   <dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2024-12-06T12:57:08Z</dcterms:created>
---
>   <dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2024-12-06T12:57:28Z</dcterms:created>

My next thought was to run the test, extract the contents of the xlsx-file, extract the contents of the other xlsx-file and then compare the corresponding folder contents ignoring the file containing the Excel creation date. But that's somehow too brittle... Besides xls-files aren't ZIP-files, so this approach cannot be applied to them.
Is there a more robust approach?

Export to CSV - should formulas, color and such be irrelevant.

@JoopEggen No. All the presentation (background colors, font styles etc.) must also be checked

Use POI to read both files and compare them. Only you know what "equal" means for you. For example two document opened on different sheets are equal?

@talexmovedtoCodidact Not quite sure what you mean. Two excel files must have the same number of sheets, sheet names must be the same, order of sheets must be the same, and sheet contents must be the same. By the way in my case there is only one sheet in excel file...

Excel remembers which sheet is open, so if you open document, select another sheet and save it, you get different document. It was just one example. There are many little things you need to make decision about.

@talexmovedtoCodidact The file is created automatically with the same algorithm. No check is required after a human did something with the file...

[Edit] your question and post your code, i.e. the code that creates the xlsx file. Then people will be able to reproduce your problem and possibly help you with it.

@ka3ak So you comparing generated files? Looks like you can get more practical answer if you give more context. Why you need to compare them? Is there any other way to track changes? Like storing hashes of generated files in DB?

It isn't clear why you want to compare them. Knowing that would make it a lot easier to answer your question usefully. MS Office code is sloppy and drag and drop of images when users edit documents can create things where they look the same but are different. BTW XLSX files are quite literally disguised ZIP files so unzipping a pair and then doing a diff between them (other comparison tools available) might be what you want.

If that contained Excel creation date is always the same number of characters, you could start by testing the number of octets in both documents. This would not tell you if they are a match, but it is a quick and easy way to see if they are not a match. That would avoid needlessly performing the more invasive checks.

@MartinBrown I want to create a test that ensures that the model is represented as expected and no functional changes break it. If one day the presentation must change, the developer defines a new expected excel file and reworks the test accordingly.

Then all you probably need to do is ignore the time & date stamp(s) and you should be home and dry. There might also be author metadata that could change when someone else on a different XL version alters the file. Drag and droop of images into existing has always been a minefield in all of the Office products. Particularly bad on sites which have multiple versions of Excel/Word in use at the same time. Old documents end up with orphaned metadata and worst case can grow in size exponentially with successive round trips.

y exporting both xlsx files to csv, then compare both files doesn't work? (imho, it's simple and robust enough)
